# Celery AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet when using Django with Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm encountering an issue with Celery and Django where I receive an "AppRegistryNotReady" exception, stating that "Apps aren't loaded yet." This occurs when attempting to run Celery with the beat scheduler.

Here are the key details:

- I'm using Django with Celery for background task processing.

- When trying to start the Celery beat scheduler using the command:

celery -A myproject beat -l info

I encounter the following traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last): ... raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

- The issue seems related to Django settings or app loading during Celery initialization.

This is my code
celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','myproject.settings')

app = Celery('myproject')
app.conf.enable_utc = False

app.conf.update(timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata')
app.config_from_object(settings, namespace = 'CELERY')

# celery beat settings  
app.conf.beat_schedule ={

}

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE ='Asia/Kolkata'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

```
from myapp.models import Client,ImportSettings
task_intervals = ImportSettings.objects.all()

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {}
for task_interval in task_intervals:
    interval_seconds = task_interval.check_frequency_minutes
    client_id = task_interval.client

    CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE[f'import-{client_id}'] = {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.process_csv_files',
        'schedule': interval_seconds,
        'args': (
            'directory_path',
            'table1',
            'table2'
        )
    }
```

**__init**__.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Tried specifying the Celery app with the full path:

celery -A myproject.celery beat -l info

Tried starting Celery beat with the `--detach` option:

celery -A myproject.celery beat --detach -l info

Checked Django settings and app loading:

Verified that Django settings and app loading are correct in **`myproject/settings.py`** and **`myproject/__init__.py`**

Ensured that Celery is configured correctly in the **`myproject/celery.py`** file

Checked for any issues in the myapp/models.py file, especially around the Import settings model.

Confirmed that the virtual environment is activated before running Celery commands.

created an entire new project and still the error persist